# Check if value is not on the list

Tags: c#, linq

I don't want values from the `List<string>` to be used.

For `List<string>` I have a function:

```
private List<string> GetManualColumns()
{
  List<string> listColumns = new List<string>();
  listColumns.Add("USER_KEY");
  listColumns.Add("USER_NAME");

  return listColumns;
}
```

I need to iterate to specific values (column names), but they must not be in the list from function `GetManualColumns()`.

How to do this?

I need something like:

```
if(col not in GetManualColumns())
{
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx) to do this.

```
if(!GetManualColumns().Contains(col))
{
     // Do Something
}
```

Comment: 8 seconds faster! damn ;)

Answer (score 4):

Use `HashSet<string>` and `Contain` method

```
private HashSet<string> GenerateManualColumns()
{
    return new HashSet<string> { "USER_KEY","USER_NAME" };
}

var manualColumns = GenerateManualColumns();
if (manualColumns.Contains(col) == false)
{

}
```

`HashSet<T>.Contain()` method is O(1) so searching will be much faster then from `List`

Comment: You can write `if (!hashSet.Contains(col))`

Comment: @aloisdg I doubt that Fabio does not know that. I have also a colleague who prefers to write it that way, for him it is more readable he says

Comment: +1 for `HashSet` usage, keeping an eye on things like this vastly benefit performance of the application.

Comment: @MongZhu it was not for fabio directly. OP or a visitor may not know that. For you colleague, if it is fine for him he should keep using it. AFAIK, for most people it is just superfluous. :)

Comment: @aloisdg sounds reasonable. I also use the `!` to negate. :)

Comment: @aloisdg as usually this kind of staff raise amount of different opinions. Just to explain mine: we, I mean developers, most of the time reading the code. Mine approach save my reading flow, it gives me possibility to understand faster. Where line `if(!hashset.Contain())` will break reading flow and forces you to "jump" forward to `Contain` part and after that "jump back" to `!` part. Then did you have sometimes moments when you missed a `!` character while reading.

Comment: I don't experiment this kind of trouble. I found the cognitive load far smaller with (IMO) cleaner solution like the use of  `!`. For me,  `(!manualColumns.Contains(col))` is to `(manualColumns.Contains(col) == false)`, what `(manualColumns.Contains(col) == false)` would be to `((manualColumns.Contains(col) == false) == true)`. If it works for you, keep going. I just say that you _can_ use `!` instead, not that you _have to_.

Answer (score 3):

This might do the trick for you

```
if (!GetManualColumns().Any(s => s == col))
{
   //Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

check whether it contains the value:

```
if(!GetManualColumns().Contains(col))
```

If you want to iterate over the columns I would suggest to avoid calling the list creation code at each column. A better way would be to get it once and use it.

```
List<string> res = GetManualColumns();
foreach (var col in columns)
{
    if (!res.Contains(col))
    {

    }
}
```